# why k4dirstat or DiskUsageAnalyzer, when run at root (/), will end up making that FS readonly?

Tags: disk-usage, reboot

Then I have to reboot and run fsck manually after that :(.

Is there any alternative app to them that wont cause that?
do you know **what directory when accessed could cause that problem**?

**Some more info:**
I found something about SMART logs:
sda sdb and sdc, all have entries at syslog like "SMART Prefailure/Usage Attribute:" about changes in "Temperature_Celsius", "Airflow_Temperature_Cel",
but only sdc had this tho "Hardware_ECC_Recovered".

k4dirstat was run at root '/' and it is at sdb (but it has a LVM mirror leg at sda).
I am not sure sdc stuff was mounted at /media when I ran k4dirstat.

may be, next time I try to run it just after a fresh boot with minimal apps running, and making sure only root '/' is mounted, I should run it again on a terminal in  verbose mode to try to catch something...

Comment: If filesystems are going ro after running any app, there's probably a potential disk failure occurring. Use the `Disks` app to review your `SMART Data & Tests`. Check syslog for disk errors with `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I added info to the OP.  sda has "43 bad sectors" where is one of the mirror legs, could be that?

Comment: It depends. Is sda the drive that's going ro? The "more info" in your question... if that's from syslog, you'd have to look at the text before/after the messages that you reported, to see if you find a ro message. In SMART, what value is `Current Pending Sector Count` and `Uncorrectable Sector Count`?

Comment: @heynnema LVM `/dev/mapper/root on /` has `errors=remount-ro`, that one goes RO. It is about sda and sdb, the LVM mirror legs. I thought bad sectors were marked to not  be used, therefore only using good ones. The log has also this  `sda [SAT], 43 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors`, mmm.. I thought that was fixed, may be not I guess? oh ok, now I found the menu option for "SMART Data & Tests" (not at the gear icon) sda: "Current Pending Sector Count"=43, "Uncorrectable Sector Count"=0

Comment: ah... syslog's `sda [SAT], 43 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors` matches SMART's `Current Pending Sector Count"=43`. Could be your problem. Potential bad sectors only get marked unusable during a WRITE operation, not READ.

Comment: I ran `fsck` and it is now 47 pending, well, at sda, one of the 2 partitions were fine already, the other one had a lot of problems. I think k4dirstat was going thru /media/ ,mounted only after I request, partitions to reach it and *bam*! RO! Next step is to try it again, I will run it b4 I go sleep to not mess my current work xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

`Syslog` and `SMART` report similar errors...

`syslog`'s sda [SAT], 43 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors matches `SMART`'s "Current Pending Sector Count"=43

Potential bad sectors only get marked unusable during a WRITE operation, not READ. That's probably why k4dirstat and Disk Usage Analyzer caused the drive to go read only.

Possible failing sda HDD.

**Update #1:**

After performing a good backup, lets check for bad blocks and see if we can map them out... maybe you'll get a little more time with this disk... if there aren't too many bad blocks.

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open the `terminal` app, and use the:

`sudo e2fsck -fcck /dev/sdaX` # yes, that's -fcck

command, where sdaX needs to be your Ubuntu partition.

The -fcck parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.
```

Comment: failing may also mean it will still become RO even after fsck right? I will try again b4 going to sleep thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower fsck may not cause it to go ro unless it hits one of those bad sectors that haven't been mapped out yet. I'd do a backup now.

Comment: sure! but as I ran k4dirstat only for 1 minute, as it was causing RO before that time, I will just fully run k4dirstat to grant the fsck in all mounted partitions was the way to prevent the RO problem :)

Comment: it is quite confusing that k4dirstat was actually writing instead of just reading as expected. anyway, I will run it fully today b4 going sleep :)

Comment: @AquariusPower see Update #1 in my answer, for how to badblock your disk.

Comment: cool thx! btw last time I ran for badblocks it took so much endless time that I give up. That hd is 1TB, if I had a no-break I could let it running before going to sleep. It would be interesting if we could resume a badblocks check from a specified block on, so we could run it for one hour every day :)

Comment: @AquariusPower if you're concerned about the time it takes to badblock, change the `-fcck` parameter to `-fck`, but understand that it may not be as thorough. Don't abort it mid-stream.

Comment: running fsck on the non-automounted partitions solved the k4dirstat side-effect fs RO problem! I let it for a huge long time w/o checking, I think more than one year!

Comment: my LVM filesystems are split in several +-20GB parts, I am quite sure I can call fsck for each part individually what could suffice :)

Comment: @AquariusPower fsck by itself won't fix a bad block problem. You'll have to do it as per my instructions.

Comment: one last note. The problematic filesystems/partitions were not really accessed by k4dirstat. They were at /media/myUser/someFolders, and k4dirstat only reported +-32kb for each of them, so it didnt dig into them, just checked their existance, and that was enough to mess things up. Unless I am missing something, and still considering it should only read and not write at all ! :>

Comment: @AquariusPower you lost me now. I'm only concerned about solving the `sda [SAT], 43 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors matches SMART's "Current Pending Sector Count"=43` errors, on whatever partition they're on.